# Get the password of the all the available WIFI networks in the nearby location

Tags: android, wifi

I am working on Android TV apps. Can some one tell me how can I get the password of the all the available WIFI networks in the nearby location? I need to check the wifi password is correct (Entered by user) before I connect the WIFI to the device when user enters the password.

Comment: You do not need to put tags at the bottom of the question, only in the tags box

Comment: You realize that if WIFI networks worked the way your question assumes it does, that would be kind of a security issue, right?

Comment: Yes. i take password input from the user after trying to connect to a network. How can i cross check if entered password is correct.

Answer (score 5):

> Can some one tell me how can i get the password of the all the available WIFI networks in the nearby location.

You don't.

> I need to check the wifi password is correct (Entered by user) before i connect the WIFI to the device when user enters the password.

You do that by trying to connect and seeing if it works.